# Delete unmatched records in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in an Access database where records may be referenced from either of two other tables. I need to delete records from that table if they are not referenced by either of the others.
My best solution so far has been to create a subquery to return the id's of the referenced records and to refer to the subquery from a delete query. (The subquery has to be separate because Access does not allow UNION in nested subqueries.)

So ...
SelectQuery:

```
SELECT TableB.id FROM TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.id = TableA.id  
UNION  
SELECT TableC.id FROM TableC INNER JOIN TableA ON TableC.id = TableA.id
```

DeleteQuery:

```
 DELETE * FROM TableA WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM SelectQuery)
```

This is excruciatingly slow ... there must be a better way?

I was trying to avoid having to add a boolean '`Used`' field to TableA ...

Comment: In the end I bit the bullet and added a Used column to Table A. Updated the Used column with two separate queries, one for each of the other tables. Then deleted all records where Used=No.  Reduced execution time from 56 minutes to 3 seconds.

Comment: 56 minutes? Even if you have no indices and are doing three complete table scans I find it hard to believe it could take that long? Were nested subqueries of entire tables being repeated per record?

Comment: Well, UNION can't use indexes, for one.

Answer (score 2):

@Matthew PK suggests using two NOT IN subqueries, which is theoretically a good idea, but as I observed in a comment, NOT IN and NOT EXISTS are poorly optimized by Jet/ACE and will often not use the indexes on both sides of the comparison. I'm wondering whether or not subqueries are necessary or not:

```
  DELETE *
  FROM (TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID) LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableA.ID = TableC.ID
  WHERE TableB.ID Is Null AND TableC.ID Is Null;
```

This would definitely use your indexes. If a subquery is necessary, you could replace TableB and TableC with the relevant subqueries.

Comment: An outer join combined with a null check is definitely the best way to go for "not in" logic. +1.

Comment: I had to change the first line to Delete TableA.* to get it to work for me in an Access query

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this:

```
DELETE FROM TableA 
WHERE 
    id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TableB)
AND
    id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TableC)
```

?

Comment: Hmmm. I might well have tried that if I hadn't made it work as I described in my comment above. It's now merely of academic interest and I don't have time to check it out. Thanks for the idea anyway.

Comment: The problem with that is that Jet/ACE poorly optimizes NOT IN and NOT EXISTS so that it doesn't necessarily utilize the indexes on both sides of the comparison.

Comment: @David, I agree, your answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable to create a new table based on your SelectQuery, delete the original table, and rename the new one to the original name?

Answer (score -1):

```
/* delete more records */

DELETE FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT field FROM table2 WHERE table2.field = table1.field)
```